# Closing lightbox permanently for a user on close button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using a jquery plugin ( lightbox) on my asp.net page(http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/#demo). This lightbox loads a page using Iframe in this lightbox. this lightbox has an image for closing popup.

I want that when user clicks this image and loads page again then this pop up doesn't appear. Right now popup appears on each time user hits F5. I  guess I need to use cookies with JS/Jquery but not exactly sure.

Comment: Cookies are your best bet.  Just set a cookie that doesn't expire on the close function

Comment: @Dameo when will it be created and when will it expire ?

Comment: You can read about localStorage and sessionStorage also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage - it's another option besides cookies

Answer (score 1):

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;

}

window.onload = function(){
    if(document.cookie.indexOf("popupopened")>-1){
        if(document.getElementById("your_popup_div")!=null){

                document.getElementById("your_popup_div").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("your_popup_div"));

        return;
    }       
} else { 
    setCookie("popupopened", "Shouldn't open again", 10);
    }
}
```